# ERROR: Cookbook loaded at path(s) has invalid metadata

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo, vagrantfile

When I'm running:

```
:$ vagrant provision
```

or

```
:$ vagrant up
```

I have an error:

```
nisevi@localhost processor (master):$ vagrant provision
Using ssh deploy key of: /home/nisevi/.ssh/id_rsa
==> default: Chef 12.0.3 Omnibus package is already installed.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
==> default: W
==> default: : Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
==> default: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
==> default: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
==> default: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
==> default: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
==> default: W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:42+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:42+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.0.3 ***
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:42+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1224
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:50+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[processor]"] from CLI options
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:50+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[processor]]
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:50+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [opsworks_initial_setup, mysql::client, dependencies, opsworks_ganglia::client, deploy::default, ba-processor::setup, ba-processor::deploy, sidekiq::deploy, opsworks_ganglia::configure-client]
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:50+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for ubuntu1404-opsworks
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:50+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:50+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:51+00:00] WARN: found a directory vendor in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping.
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:51+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:51+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:51+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:51+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook loaded at path(s) [/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/cookbooks/tad-server] has invalid metadata: The `name' attribute is required in cookbook metadata
==> default: [2015-01-07T03:09:51+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error or to what is related?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error mentions, you *must* add `name 'tad-server'` the `metadata.rb` file in this cookbook. In days long past, this was optional so many people didn't put a metadata.rb in their cookbooks at all, but some tools now require this at a minimum. All other fields in the metadata remain optional, though `version` is highly recommended.

Comment: @Fawzan ...the metadata.rb at the root directory of the cookbook you're having the issue with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your cookbook name to the metadata.rb file inside the cookbook directory.
I just ran into this with the chef-client cookbook. Upload failed till I added the following line to chef-client/metadata.rb

```
name "chef-client"
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning to add the name of the cookbook in the metadata.rb. Someting like `name "cookbook-name"`.